# C++ winapi scale2x algorithm. Is it well implemented?

Tags: c++, winapi

taking into account the **scale2x** algorithm for scaling an image to 2x.
Im using **winapi** in an Emulator.
When tha scale2x algorithm is used **i don't see too much difference in the image scaled2x** as it states in [Scale2x algorithm](https://www.scale2x.it/algorithm)

My C++ class is as follows:

```
typedef unsigned long pixel_32;
class Scale2x
{
    pixel_32 * surface = 0, * ptr_surface = 0;
    pixel_32* surface_scale2x = 0, * surface_scale2x_ptr;
    int width, height;
    pixel_32 B = 0, D = 0, F = 0, H = 0;
    pixel_32 E0 = 0, E1 = 0, E2 = 0, E3 = 0;
    pixel_32 E = 0;
    void Scale()
    {
        if (B != H && D != F) {
            E0 = D == B ? D : E;
            E1 = B == F ? F : E;
            E2 = D == H ? D : E;
            E3 = H == F ? F : E;
        }
        else {
            E0 = E;
            E1 = E;
            E2 = E;
            E3 = E;
        }
    }
public:
    Scale2x(int p_width, int p_height) : width(p_width), height(p_height)
    {
        surface = new pixel_32[width * height];
        surface_scale2x = new pixel_32[width * height * 2*4];
        surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;
    }
    void SetSourceSurface(pixel_32* source_sourface)
    {
        memcpy(surface, source_sourface, width * height * 2);
    }
    void PutPixel(pixel_32 pixel)
    {
        *ptr_surface = pixel;
        ptr_surface++;
    }
    void Lock()
    {
        ptr_surface = surface;
    }
    void ScaleImage()
    {
        ptr_surface = surface;
        surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;
        int double_width = width * 2;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                E = *ptr_surface;
                B = ptr_surface[-width];
                H = ptr_surface[+width];
                D = ptr_surface[-1];
                F = ptr_surface[+1];
                ptr_surface++;
                Scale();
                surface_scale2x_ptr[0] = E0;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[1] = E1;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width] = E2;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width + 1] = E3;
                surface_scale2x_ptr += 2;
            }
            surface_scale2x_ptr += double_width;
        }
    }
    pixel_32 * GetScaledPtr()
    {
        surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;
        return surface_scale2x;
    }
};
```

**Scale2x image:**
[image]

**Raw image:**
[image]

There can be seen that the image effectivly changes, but they are my eyes that i don't see too much difference.

In a nutshell: is the algorithm implemented well?

Comment: What are you expecting more? The top image is smoother.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of challenges to reviewing this:

1. You don’t mention what version(s) of C++ you are targeting. I will assume C++20, because that’s the current standard.
2. You don’t provide any example of how this code is going to be used. I have no way of knowing if this interface is required, or if I can suggest a completely different interface. I will assume the interface can be completely rewritten.
3. You don’t provide any description of requirements. For example, can I assume that `p_width` and `p_height` will never be negative? Or zero? Can I assume `source_sourface` in `SetSourceSurface()` will never be `nullptr`? I will just have to make guesses here.
4. You don’t provide any example code or test code, so I have literally no idea how you expect this code to be used. Again, I’ll just have to make guesses.

I will also not be checking that the algorithm is correctly implemented; this is CodeReview, so I assume it is. What you *should* do is write test cases to confirm this.

## Design review

Before reviewing the actual code, I usually do a review of the overall design.

The big problem with the design of this code is that it seems bizarrely over-engineered. You are implementing the “winapi scale2x algorithm”. The key word there is “algorithm”. (I don’t actually see what the Windows API has to do with anything, but whatever.) Algorithms are not classes; algorithms are functions. Just take a look at [the C++ `<algorithm>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm); other than the execution policies (which are not algorithms) there’s literally not a single class in it. (Well, I mean, not counting neibloids.)

You don’t provide any sample code to show how this class is supposed to be used, so I have to guess that common usage would be something like this:

```
// source = an array of 61440 (256x240) unsigned longs
// draw() = function that draws an image

auto scale2x = Scale2x{256, 240};   // create your scalar
scale2x.SetSourceSurface(source);   // copy the source image
scale2x.ScaleImage();               // do the scaling
draw(scale2x.GetScaledPtr());       // do something with the result
```

This is… ugly, to say the least. Not to mention wildly inefficient. I would like to be able to write code like this:

```
auto const scaled = scale2x(source, 256, 240);
draw(scaled);
```

Or even just:

```
draw(scale2x(source, 256, 240));
```

It doesn’t make a lot of sense to have a class that copies the entire source image, just so it can hold on to it to scale later. Why not just scale it right away?

That being said, because you haven’t given nearly enough information about your requirements, I have no idea what functions like `Lock()` and `PutPixel()` are for. They seem pointless, but for all I know, there’s some API requirement you haven’t mentioned.

The first step to writing good C++ code is to stop and think… the worst programmers I’ve ever seen are the ones who hear a problem and then immediately start banging on the keyboard. No, the right way to program is to stop and think about what it is you are trying to do. What is the model of your problem? Where are the “things” (objects) and “actions” (functions) in your problem?

You’re scaling images, so right away it should be obvious that you need an image class:

```
class image {};
```

What properties does an image have? Well, it’s got a width and a height, and a bunch of pixels:

```
using pixel = unsigned long;    // okay for now, but you should really make a
                                // proper pixel type

class image
{
    using size_type = int;

    size_type width;
    size_type height;
    std::unique_ptr<pixel[]> pixels;
};
```

Just that much already prevents a whole slew of bugs that your code is vulnerable to. For example:

```
auto img_1 = std::array<pixel_32, 32*32>{};   // a 32x32 image
auto img_2 = std::array<pixel_32, 16*16>{};   // a 16x16 image


auto scale2x_1 = Scale2x{32, 32};   // scaler meant for img_1, which is 32x32
scale2x_1.SetSourceSurface(img_2);  // uh-oh, accidentally used img_2, which is 16x16!

// crash!
```

If the image itself knows its size, then you can’t possibly make this error. That’s what good C++ looks like.

Once you have a proper image type, then your scale algorithm is obviously just:

```
auto scale2x(image const& src)
{
    // create a new image of the correct size

    // do the scaling from src into the new image

    // return the new image
}
```

As you can see, there’s no need for a class.

So I would advise you to step back and rethink your problem, and then try to model it properly. That will not only make your code less likely to have silly or dangerous bugs, it will also make it more efficient.

## Code review

```
typedef unsigned long pixel_32;
```

This is the old-fashioned, C way of doing type aliases. The much better, much clearer modern version is:

```
using pixel_32 = unsigned long;
```

Now, I don’t know if you *have* to use `unsigned long` as the pixel type, because you didn’t give the requirements. Assuming you have a choice, then you should make a proper pixel class. At the very least you might consider using `std::uint_fast32_t` or—if you don’t care about portability—`std::uint32_t` rather than `unsigned long`, because it more clearly indicates that you really want a 32-bit type. `unsigned long` is guaranteed to be *at least* 32 bits, but it can be much, much more.

```
    pixel_32 * surface = 0, * ptr_surface = 0;
```

There is a *lot* wrong here.

First, never, ever declare multiple variables on the same line. That is terrible practice.

Second, since at least C++11, we don’t use `0` as a null pointer constant; we have `nullptr`.

So, so far, that means:

```
    pixel_32* surface = nullptr;
    pixel_32* ptr_surface = nullptr;
```

But the biggest issue is the use of naked pointers at all. Naked pointers are a code smell. And the worst part is, you are using these naked pointers in absolutely the worst possible way: as owning pointers to array memory. That’s one of the worst things you can possibly do in modern C++ code.

Let’s start with `surface`. This is supposed to be a dynamically-sized array of pixels, where the size of the array is determined by `width` and `height`. For dynamically-sized arrays, you *normally* use `std::vector`; that should be your first choice here. *However*… your use case is special, because the size is not a single number: it’s calculated from the width and the height. If you use `std::vector`, that means duplicated information. Also, you don’t need the array to be resizable; you size it once when constructing it, and then that’s its size forever. Given all that, you could do better than `std::vector<pixel_32>` by using `std::unique_ptr<pixel_32[]>` instead. It’s *almost* a drop-in replacement for `std::vector` in this case, but you do have to do a bit more manual work.

Now, as for `ptr_surface`… I don’t really see any point to it. The only place it seems to have any purpose is `PutPixel()`… which is a terrible function for reasons I’ll get to later. I say just dump it.

So that gives:

```
    std::unique_ptr<pixel_32[]> surface = nullptr;
```

The same logic applies for `surface_scale2x` and `surface_scale2x_ptr`, except that `surface_scale2x_ptr` seems to be *completely* useless. `surface_ptr` is a terrible idea, but at least it has a point (a bad point, but a point). `surface_scale2x_ptr` does absolutely nothing except waste space.

```
    int width, height;
```

Again, each of these should be on its own line. And while you’re at it, you might as well add initializers.

```
    pixel_32 B = 0, D = 0, F = 0, H = 0;
    pixel_32 E0 = 0, E1 = 0, E2 = 0, E3 = 0;
    pixel_32 E = 0;
```

All of these are wrong. These should all be local variables to the scaling functions, not class data members. (But then, none of this should be a class at all.)

```
    void Scale()
    {
        if (B != H && D != F) {
            E0 = D == B ? D : E;
            E1 = B == F ? F : E;
            E2 = D == H ? D : E;
            E3 = H == F ? F : E;
        }
        else {
            E0 = E;
            E1 = E;
            E2 = E;
            E3 = E;
        }
    }
```

This is a terrible function, because it uses class data members rather than parameters, which leads to spooky action at a distance, and bugs that are going to be impossible to diagnose.

To fix this, the first step is to use C++ conventions, and not use uppercase variable names. Uppercase variable names are reserved for macros, and—for single-letter names only, or single-letter-and-number names—template parameter names.

The second step is to make all those outside variables into local variables and return values:

```
    auto Scale(pixel_32 e, pixel_32 b, pixel_32 h, pixel_32 d, pixel_32 f)
    {
        if (b != h && d != f) {
            return std::tuple{
                d == b ? d : e,
                b == f ? f : e,
                d == h ? d : e,
                h == f ? f : e
            };
        }
        else {
            return std::tuple{e, e, e, e};
        }
    }
```

This is still terrible, but it’s getting slightly better. Doing this allows us to mark the function as `constexpr` and `noexcept`, both of which offer potential performance gains:

```
    constexpr auto Scale(pixel_32 e, pixel_32 b, pixel_32 h, pixel_32 d, pixel_32 f) noexcept
    {
        if (b != h && d != f) {
            return std::tuple{
                d == b ? d : e,
                b == f ? f : e,
                d == h ? d : e,
                h == f ? f : e
            };
        }
        else {
            return std::tuple{e, e, e, e};
        }
    }
```

You could also eliminate the repetition with a local lambda:

```
    constexpr auto Scale(pixel_32 e, pixel_32 b, pixel_32 h, pixel_32 d, pixel_32 f) noexcept
    {
        // give these proper names, of course, or at least comments explaining
        // the pattern
        auto const x1 = [e](auto v1, auto v2) { return v1 == v2 ? v1 : e; };
        auto const x2 = [e](auto v1, auto v2) { return v1 == v2 ? v2 : e; };

        if (b != h && d != f)
            return std::tuple{x1(d, b), x2(b, f), x1(d, h), x2(h, f)};
        else
            return std::tuple{e, e, e, e};
    }
```

Let’s put this function aside for the moment, but we’ll come back to it.

```
    Scale2x(int p_width, int p_height) : width(p_width), height(p_height)
    {
        surface = new pixel_32[width * height];
        surface_scale2x = new pixel_32[width * height * 2*4];
        surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;
    }
```

You are using naked pointers as owning pointers, you are using `new`, but you never once use `delete` anywhere in your code. Your code leaks memory like a sieve. If you were to attempt to use this in an actual game emulator, which will likely need to run this function on the entire screen every frame, you’d probably crash the system in a matter of minutes (or, more likely, trigger the OOM manager, which will start killing processes until the emulator itself finally dies).

On the other hand, if you use smart pointers or containers, you won’t have this problem.

```
    void SetSourceSurface(pixel_32* source_sourface)
    {
        memcpy(surface, source_sourface, width * height * 2);
    }
```

Avoid low-level C library functions like `std::memcpy()` in C++. For this, you should use:

```
    void SetSourceSurface(pixel_32* source_surface)
    {
        std::copy_n(source_surface, width * height * 2, surface);
    }
```

But overall, this is a terrible function, because there is no way to be sure that `source_sourface` (watch the spelling: “source sour face”!) points to an array of the right size. In fact, I’m pretty sure you have it wrong! Look closely. Should it not be `width * height`, and not `width * height * 2`?

That’s just one sample of the many, many bugs you will have in your code because you’re not using proper types.

```
    void PutPixel(pixel_32 pixel)
    {
        *ptr_surface = pixel;
        ptr_surface++;
    }
```

I don’t see what the point of this function is at all. There is a concept in programming called the “single responsibility principle”. Basically one “thing”—class, object, function, whatever—should have one and only one job. If the job of `Scale2x` is to scale images… then that’s its job. It is not its job to *also* be a drawing surface you can colour on. It should take an image source, scale it, and then return it, and then be done. If someone wants to doodle on either the source image or the scaled image, fine… but that’s no longer `Scale2x`’s job. (That should be the job of a dedicated image class.)

In any case, this function is terrible and dangerous for other reasons, too, not least being there is no checking or control to make sure you don’t blow past the end of `surface` and start overwriting other memory.

```
    void Lock()
    {
        ptr_surface = surface;
    }
```

All this seems to be doing is resetting the “write-to” pointer back to the start of the image. I don’t see how this is “locking” anything, in any sense.

I’m going to skip `ScaleImage()` for the moment, and go to `GetScaledPtr()`:

```
    pixel_32 * GetScaledPtr()
    {
        surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;
        return surface_scale2x;
    }
```

The convention in C++ is to put the type modifier—the `*` for pointers, and the `&` or `&&` for references—with the type. In other words:

- `pixel_32 *GetScaledPtr()` is C style.
- `pixel_32* GetScaledPtr()` is C++ style.
- `pixel_32 * GetScaledPtr()` is just confused.

The first line of the function seems completely pointless.

Now let’s get to the actual meat of the class, the `ScaleImage()` function:

```
    void ScaleImage()
    {
        ptr_surface = surface;
        surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;
        int double_width = width * 2;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                E = *ptr_surface;
                B = ptr_surface[-width];
                H = ptr_surface[+width];
                D = ptr_surface[-1];
                F = ptr_surface[+1];
                ptr_surface++;
                Scale();
                surface_scale2x_ptr[0] = E0;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[1] = E1;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width] = E2;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width + 1] = E3;
                surface_scale2x_ptr += 2;
            }
            surface_scale2x_ptr += double_width;
        }
    }
```

One of the main reasons this class is so bad is that it uses class data members when it *should* be using local variables. Putting all those variables—`B`, `D`, and so on—in the class is not just bad design, it’s also less efficient. If all those variables were local, they could probably be optimized to register-only variables, rather than having to read from and write to memory (slow!!!).

So as a first pass, let’s make everything local that can be (and give them proper names, too), and spread things out a bit:

```
    auto ScaleImage()
    {
        auto ptr_surface = surface;
        auto surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;

        auto double_width = width * 2;

        for (auto y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (auto x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                auto const e = ptr_surface[0];
                auto const b = ptr_surface[-width];
                auto const h = ptr_surface[+width];
                auto const d = ptr_surface[-1];
                auto const f = ptr_surface[+1];

                ptr_surface++;

                Scale(); // we'll fix this next, ignore it for now

                surface_scale2x_ptr[0] = E0;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[1] = E1;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width] = E2;
                surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width + 1] = E3;

                surface_scale2x_ptr += 2;
            }

            surface_scale2x_ptr += double_width;
        }
    }
```

Now, remember how I refactored `Scale()` above to use parameters and return values, rather than spooky action at a distance variables? That means we can write this:

```
    auto ScaleImage()
    {
        auto ptr_surface = surface;
        auto surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;

        auto double_width = width * 2;

        for (auto y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (auto x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                std::tie(
                    surface_scale2x_ptr[0],
                    surface_scale2x_ptr[1],
                    surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width],
                    surface_scale2x_ptr[double_width + 1]
                ) =
                    Scale(
                        ptr_surface[0],
                        ptr_surface[-width],
                        ptr_surface[+width],
                        ptr_surface[-1],
                        ptr_surface[+1]
                    );

                ptr_surface++;

                surface_scale2x_ptr += 2;
            }

            surface_scale2x_ptr += double_width;
        }
    }
```

Hmm, I really think that big chunk of code in the middle needs to be refactored out better:

```
constexpr auto scale2x_internal_pixel_(pixel_32 const* src, pixel_32* dest_top_left, int src_width) noexcept
{
    auto const dest_width = src_width * 2;

    auto const e = src[0];
    auto const b = src[-width];
    auto const h = src[+width];
    auto const d = src[-1];
    auto const f = src[+1];

    if (b != h && d != f) {
        dest_top_left[0]              = (d == b) ? d : e;
        dest_top_left[1]              = (b == f) ? f : e;
        dest_top_left[dest_width]     = (d == h) ? d : e;
        dest_top_left[dest_width + 1] = (h == f) ? f : e;
    }
    else {
        dest_top_left[0]              = e;
        dest_top_left[1]              = e;
        dest_top_left[dest_width]     = e;
        dest_top_left[dest_width + 1] = e;
    }
}

auto ScaleImage()
{
    auto ptr_surface = surface;
    auto surface_scale2x_ptr = surface_scale2x;

    for (auto y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (auto x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            scale2x_internal_pixel_(ptr_surface, surface_scale2x_ptr, width);

            ptr_surface++;

            surface_scale2x_ptr += 2;
        }

        surface_scale2x_ptr += width * 2;
    }
}
```

Now we can really clean up the function:

```
auto ScaleImage(pixel_32 const* p_src, int width, int height)
{
    // create the output image
    auto dest = std::unique_ptr<pixel_32[]>{new pixel_32[(width * 2) * (height * 2)]};

    auto p_dest = dest.get(); // to make it easier to iterate

    // using auto and decltype makes the code future-proof
    for (auto y = decltype(height){0}; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (auto x = decltype(width){0}; x < width; ++x)
        {
            scale2x_internal_pixel_(p_src, p_dest, width);

            ++p_src;

            p_dest += 2;
        }

        p_dest += width * 2;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Now that the function has been simplified, there are some obvious problems visible. I know I said I wasn’t going to review the algorithm, but some of these issues are far too basic to ignore.

The scale2x algorithm takes the pixel `E` in this:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

And, using the values of `B`, `D`, `F`, and `H`, calculates four output pixels.

Okay… but… what if there is no `B`, `D`, `F`, and `H`?

Let’s look at your code again. Let’s just look at the loop, and assume the source width is 8 pixels and height is 6 pixels, and it’s the first iteration, so `x` and `y` are both zero:

```
        ptr_surface = surface;

        // ... [snip] ...

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                E = *ptr_surface;
                B = ptr_surface[-width];
                H = ptr_surface[+width];
                D = ptr_surface[-1];
                F = ptr_surface[+1];

                // ... [snip] ...
            }

            // ... [snip] ...
        }

        // ... [snip] ...
```

Now, on the very first iteration, `ptr_surface` is the same as `surface`, right? And `surface` is an array of pixels from `surface[0]` to `surface[width * height]`, which is `surface[8 * 6]` or `surface[48]`, right? So reading any pixel from `surface[0]` to `surface[47]` is okay… anything else is reading from other memory… which is bad.

So on the first iteration:

```
E = surface[0];
B = surface[-8];   // !!!
H = surface[+8];
D = surface[-1];    // !!!
F = surface[+1];
```

See what you’ve just done?

What went wrong?

Well, the source image looks like this, where each square is a pixel:

```
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
```

When you are running the scale2x algorithm on the fifth pixel of the third row (for example), there are no problems:

```
□□□□□□□□
□□□■■■□□
□□□■■■□□
□□□■■■□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
```

But when you are running the algorithm on the fifth pixel of the *first* row…:

```
⬚⬚⬚◇◇◇⬚⬚
□□□■■■□□
□□□■■■□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
```

The dotted squares are memory *outside* the image memory… and the diamonds are places where you are illegally reading memory.

So this is what’s happening—in theory—on that first iteration:

```
⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚
⬚◇◇◇⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚
⬚◇■■□□□□□□⬚⬚
⬚◇■■□□□□□□⬚⬚
⬚⬚□□□□□□□□⬚⬚
⬚⬚□□□□□□□□⬚⬚
⬚⬚□□□□□□□□⬚⬚
⬚⬚□□□□□□□□⬚⬚
⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚
⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚
```

As you can see, the reads for `B` and `D` are reading illegal memory outside of `surface`.

(This is what’s happening in reality, because memory is not actually two-dimensional.):

```
⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚◇
◇◇⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚◇
■■□□□□□■
■■□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
□□□□□□□□
⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚
⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚⬚
```

Here’s the problem: if your image is 8×6 pixels, then the only pixels you can do the full scale2x algorithm on are the ones shaded black:

```
□□□□□□□□
□■■■■■■□
□■■■■■■□
□■■■■■■□
□■■■■■■□
□□□□□□□□
```

In other words, you can’t do the naïve algorithm on the edges. For an 8×6 image, you can only do the naïve algorithm on the 6×4 bit in the middle.

The algorithm description even says so, but you have to read carefully or you miss it:

> The image border is computed reusing the value of the nearest pixel on the border when the value of a pixel over the border is required.

So what you have to do is handle the border specially. You actually need ***NINE*** different algorithms to handle all the cases:

```
╔ ╤ ╤ ╤ ╤ ╤ ╤ ╗

╟ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ╢

╟ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ╢

╟ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ╢

╟ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┼ ╢

╚ ╧ ╧ ╧ ╧ ╧ ╧ ╝
```

That’s 4 special cases for the corners (“╔”, “╗”, “╚”, and “╝”), 1 for the top border (“╤”), 1 for the left border (“╟”), 1 for the right border (“╢”), 1 for the bottom border (“╧”), and 1 for the big chunk in the middle (“┼”).

You also need to consider degenerate cases, like a single-pixel source image, or a source image that is 1×N or N×1 pixels (or zero pixels in any dimension, perhaps). Perhaps the most efficient solution would be to handle the top and bottom rows and the left and right columns separately, because they require special attention (probably just clamping the indices would work)… and then, if and only if the size is greater than 2 in *both* dimensions, run the algorithm on the middle pixels in one fell swoop.

## Summary

Your overall design is clunky, and makes no sense. Scale2x is an algorithm, so it should be a function, not a class.

You are also abusing the idea of a class, by using class data members when you should be using local variables and/or function parameters or return values. This makes your code spaghetti code, with functions accessing variables willy-nilly, which is guaranteed to lead to bugs when things get changed in one place far away from where they’re used.

Your code is in dire need of some proper types. A good image class will solve 90% of the interface, efficiency, and spaghetti code problems. With a proper image class, the scale2x algorithm would naturally exist as a function:

```
// scale2x takes an image, and returns a new image that's been scaled
auto scale2x(image const&) -> image;
```

A properly written image class could also have bounds-checking—even if only in debug mode—which would have caught most, if not all of the bugs that currently exist in your code.

And finally, and most importantly, ***TEST YOUR CODE***. I don’t mean just try it and see if it sorta-kinda looks like it maybe produces the right output possibly. I mean **write proper tests**. Use a test framework: my favourite is Boost.Test, but that’s *really* heavyweight. You could use GoogleTest or Catch2 or whatever you like. But whatever you use, ***TEST YOUR CODE***. Test *everything* you can think of. Test what happens when you try to scale a 0×0 image (if that’s a possibility). Test what happens when you try to scale a 1×1 image. Test every possible edge case! Anyway you can imagine the algorithm failing… test it! And, of course, test the ways you expect it succeed as well. For example:

```
TEST_CASE("1x1 image should produce a 2x2 image with the single pixel repeated")
{
    // 1x1 image whose single pixel is red
    auto const src = image{red};

    // 2x2 image whose pixels are all red
    auto const expected = image{
        {red, red},
        {red, red},
    };

    TEST(scale2x(src) == expected);
}

TEST_CASE("1x2 image")
{
    auto const src = image{
        {red},
        {blue},
    };

    auto const expected = image{
        {red, red},
        {red, red},
        {blue, blue},
        {blue, blue},
    };

    TEST(scale2x(src) == expected);
}

TEST_CASE("example on algorithm description page")
{
    // the example page gives you a before and after, so copy both those
    // images' data, and test!
}

// and so on...
```

A proper image class + testing will give you the confidence that your code is implemented well.